# Proving a result on divisibility

Tags: number-theory

Let $n \ge 3$ be an integer , I need to show

(a) $6| n^{n^{n}}- n^{n}$ , and

(b) $9|n^{n^{n^{n}}}- n^{n^{n}}$

I am trying to prove both these by induction  but unable to proceed as I am confused by the endless series of algebraic manipulations that follow to prove the induction step.

Can someone tell me a better way to solve these? it would be helpful to know the technique for solving (a), so I can use it for (b) as well.

Thank you.

Comment: If $n$ is odd or even, then $n^n$ and $n^{n^n}$ are both odd or both even, respectively, so their difference is divisible by $2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How do I show they are divisible by $3$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$1^1\equiv 1\pmod{6}$$
$$2^2\equiv 4\pmod{6}$$
$$3^3\equiv 3\pmod{6}$$
$$4^4\equiv 4\pmod{6}$$
$$5^5\equiv 5\pmod{6}$$

I can be observed that for all $n\leq 6,\space n\neq 2$, we have $n^n\equiv n\pmod{6}$

This means that $n^{n^n}\equiv n^n\pmod{6}\ \forall n\not\equiv 2\pmod{6}$.

Now when $n\equiv 2\pmod{6}$, $n^n\equiv 2^2\equiv 4\pmod{6}$ and $n^{n^n}\equiv n^4\equiv 2^4\equiv 4\pmod{6}$, thus $n^{n^n}\equiv n^n\pmod{6}\ \forall n\equiv 2\pmod{6}$

Thus $6|n^{n^n}-n^n\ \forall n\in \mathbb Z,\space n\geq 3$

I think you can solve part $2$ now

Answer (score 0):

$$A=n^{n^n}-n^n=n^n[(n^n)^{n-1}-1]$$

case 1: $n-1=2k$ the we have:

$$A=n^n[(n^{kn})^2-1]=n^n(n^{kn}-1)(n^{kn}+1)$$

If $kn=2m+1$ then:

$n^n-1|(n^{kn}-1)$

$n^n+1|(n^{kn}+1)$

Therefore:

$(n^n-1)(n^n)(n^n+1)|A$

This product of three consecutive numbers which is divisible bt $6$.

Similar thing happens when $n-1=2k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

(a)

It is not difficult to show that $n^{n^n}-n^n$ and $n^n-n$ is divisible by $2$. Write $n^n-n=2m$

Now
$$n^{n^n}-n^n=n^n(n^{n^n-n}-1)=n^n(n^{2m}-1)$$
If $n$ is divisible by $3$, then $n^{n^n}-n^n$ is also divisible by $3$

If not then we have $(n,3)=1, $ then Fermat's theorem implies $n^2 \equiv 1 \mathop{mod} 3$. Thus

$$n^2 \equiv 1 \mathop{mod} 3 \\
 n^{2m} \equiv 1 \mathop{mod} 3 \\
n^{2m}-1 \equiv 0 \mathop{mod} 3 
$$

Thus we conclude that $n^{2m}-1=n^{n^n-n}-1$ is divisible by $3$. This proves that $n^{n^n}-n $ is divisible by $6$

(b)

$$n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}=n^{n^n}(n^{n^{n^n}-n^n}-1)$$
Using the previous problem, we know that $n^{n^n}-n^n$ is divisible by $6$. Write $n^{n^n}-n^n=6k$

$$n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}=n^{n^n}(n^{6k}-1) $$
Then when $n$ is divisible by $3$, then it is trivial to show that $n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}$ is divisible by $9$.

if not,then $(n,9)=1$ and Euler's theorem implies
$$n^6 \equiv 1 \mathop{mod} 9 \\
 n^{6k} \equiv 1 \mathop{mod} 9 \\
n^{6k}-1 \equiv 0 \mathop{mod} 9 
$$

This proves that $n^{n^{n^n}}-n^{n^n}$ is divisible by $9$.